Only first 3 values are insterted from next.js to mysql Workbench
I have this in app.js
app.post('/api/add-order-cui', async (req, res) => {
  const {
    cui,
    email,
    phone,
    billingCUI, // Add other fields if necessary
  } = req.body;

  console.log('Received request body:', req.body); // Log received data

  if (!cui || !email || !phone || !billingCUI) {
    return res.status(400)
      .json({
        error: 'Required fields are missing'
      });
  }

  try {
    const connection = await mysql.createConnection(dbConfig);
    const uuid = uuidv4(); // Generate a new UUID

    const query = `
      INSERT INTO orders (uuid, orderCUI, email, phone, billingCUI)
      VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    `;
    const [result] = await connection.execute(query, [uuid, cui, email, phone, billingCUI]);

    console.log('Database insertion result:', result); // Log insertion result

    await connection.end();

    return res.status(201).json({
      message: 'Order added successfully',
      orderId: result.insertId
    });


  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Database error:', error);
    return res.status(500)
      .json({
        error: 'Database error'
      });
  }
});

and this is the handleSubmit function
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const formData = {
    cui: 'aaa',
    email: 'test@email.com',
    phone: '1234445556',
    billingCUI: 'test-billing-cui',
    // Add other fields if necessary
  };

  console.log('Form data before submission:', formData);

  try {
    const response = await fetch('/api/add-order-cui', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    console.log('Response data:', data);

    if (response.ok) {
      alert(data.message);
    } else {
      alert('Error: ' + data.error);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    alert('There was an error adding the order');
  }
};

If I write the SQL code in workbench
INSERT INTO orders (uuid, orderCUI, email, phone, billingCUI)
VALUES ('test-uuid', 'test-cui', 'test@example.com', '1234567890', 'test-billing-cui');

everything works, but when I click on the button handleSubmit, the only values inserted are uuid, email and cui.
How can I fix this?

I verified the connection to the database and it works
I verified that the data can be inserted with SQL command
I checked for triggers
I verified the names of the columns, the type of the columns


Recently I have face same type of issue for oracle SQL Server.
Need to perform committing transaction after perform the update/insert
Please update query as follows:
... ... ...
... ... ...
const query = `
      INSERT INTO orders (uuid, orderCUI, email, phone, billingCUI)
      VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    `;
const [result] = await connection.execute(query, [uuid, cui, email, phone, billingCUI]);
console.log('Database insertion result:', result); // Log insertion result

// Commit the transaction after successful insertion
await connection.commit(); 

await connection.end();
... ... ...
... ... ...

It should work
